# Html.DropDownListFor - how to post back to a specific action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an Html.DropDownListFor that affects other controls on my page. When it changes, I need to make changes (hide, show, etc.) to other controls on the page. I have it sort-of working but I'm running into a problem when I change the DDL value multiple times.

The first time I change the selected value, it posts back (yeah, I know... not really a postback) to my chosen action in the controller. The action does its thing and returns the view. The problem is that when I change the selected value again, it doesn't go to the action because the URL has changed and is wrong.

In my CSHTML I have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFormToControllerAction(controllerName, actionName, queryStringParameters) {
    var url = controllerName + "/" + actionName;
    var $frm = $('form');
    $frm.attr("action",  url);
    $frm.attr("method", "Post");
    $frm.submit();
}
```

Then I call it from the DropDownList like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Province, Model.ProvinceList, new onchange = @"submitFormToControllerAction('MyController', 'MyMethod');"
```

})

And my controller action looks something like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(MyModel model)
    {
        // do something here
        return View("MyController", model);
    }
```

The first time in, my URL looks like:

> .../MVC/MyController

After changing the selected value, the URL becomes:

> .../MVC/MyController/MyMethod

After changing the selected value a second time, the URL becomes:

> .../MVC/MyController/MyController/MyMethod

Obviously, this last one fails. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm relatively new to MVC and don't know much jquery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Carlo.

Comment: Not clear on your issue, but going to a view from the POST (in a non-error scenario) may not work as you think. Recommended approach is [PRG (POST-Redirect-GET)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You could also try doing a ModelState.Clear() before you return to the view.

Comment: Steve. We're trying to port an ASP.Net app into MVC. I come from the ASP.Net world so, for me it's simple but MVC is a challenge. All I want to do is (probably using the wrong terminology here) populate the controls on my page and when a user changes a selected value on a DDL, go back to the controller, make whatever changes are required based on the different selected value (hide/show other controls, load different data, etc) and redisplay the page.

Comment: The approach I like is 1) Load all the data I'm going to need into a ViewModel [GET]. 2) Display the View and use razor to show or hide stuff initially. 3) Make jquery calls client side if needed to show or hide controls dynamically. 4) Possibly make ajax calls if a control(s) needs dramatically different data.

Comment: So you put all that logic on the client side?

Comment: Depends. If you are just hiding or showing controls - yes. If the drop down determines and entirely different set of controls are needed I would probably call a few different controller actions that return partial views similar to [this](http://www.programmerguide.net/2013/11/loading-partialview-via-jquery-in.html)

Comment: Thanks Steve! That link ALMOST does everything I need. The problem with the sample code is that it doesn't propagate any part of the PartialViewModel to the action. The action simply creates a new object, populates it and returns it. This is diverging from my original post so I've created a new post here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920279/passing-model-to-javascript-and-actions-questions)