# Passing model to javascript and actions questions

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I’m new to MVC and I’m having a lot of trouble with Partial Views. Hopefully someone can give me some guidance.

We’re trying to port our ASP.Net webforms app to MVC. I’ve created a little test app to try to mimic what we’re doing on many of our pages. Based on sample code I found [here](http://www.programmerguide.net/2013/11/loading-partialview-via-jquery-in.html), I have a View and a Partial view and a Model that contains the Partial model. The view has a drop down list that hides/shows the partial view.

When the user selects Hidden, I have a javascript method that hides the partial view. If they select Visible, the javascript makes a call to an action where I want to be able to modify the model and send it back to the view. I will also need to be able to hide or show other partial views on the page. In another scenario, I will need to be able to modify TestModel and PartialModel within the javascript function itself and re-render (have the changes reflected to the user).

I currently have two things I can't figure out:

1. How to access the model in the javascript function
2. How to pass the model back and forth to the action called from the model

The code, as it stands now, calls the action in which I create a new PartialModel and pass it back to the view. That works but when I click on the save button, the "old" PartialModel is passed to the HTTPPost action. However, I need to modify the existing model and not create a new one.

I've posted the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Controller**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestModel tm = new TestModel();
            tm.Vis = Visibility.Visible;

            return View(tm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(TestModel tm)
        {
            return View(tm);
        }

        public ActionResult DDLChangedAction(int id)
        {
            // I need access to TestModel including TestModel.PartialModel
            var pvm = new PartialModel();
            pvm.PartialInt = 100;
            pvm.PartialString = id.ToString(); ;
            pvm.PartialString2 = "asdf";

            ////return PartialView("_PartialTest", pvm,
            ////        new ViewDataDictionary(System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelper.ViewData)
            ////        {
            ////            TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = HtmlHelper.NameFor(m => m.Partial).ToString() }
            ////        });

            return PartialView("_PartialTest", pvm);
        }

        private ActionResult PartialView(string v, PartialModel pvm, ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public TestModel()
        {
            Partial = new PartialModel();
            Partial.PartialInt = 42;
            Partial.PartialString = "partialString text";
            Partial.PartialString2 = "partialString2 text";
        }

        public int SelectedItem { get; set; }

        public Visibility Vis { get; set; }

        public PartialModel Partial { get; set; }
    }

    public class PartialModel
    {
        public int PartialInt { get; set; }
        public string PartialString { get; set; }
        public string PartialString2 { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Visibility
    {
        Visible = 1,
        Hidden
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.Label("Visibility", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
           <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Vis", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Visibility))),
                            "Select",
                            new {
                                @id = "ddlVis",
                                @class = "form-control"
                                //onchange = @"ddlChanged();"
                            })
            </div>
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedItem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="partialPlaceHolder">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialTest", Model.Partial,
                    new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewData)
                    {
                        TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = Html.NameFor(m => m.Partial).ToString() }
                    })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#ddlVis').change(function () {

            /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
            var selectedID = $(this).val();
            if (selectedID == 1) {
                // access and modify the model and partial model
            }

            if ($('#ddlVis').val() == "Visible") {
                // I can pass an integer here, but how do I pass in the model to the action?
                $.get('/Test/DDLChangedAction/' + 123, function (data) {
                    /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
                    $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
                    $('#partialPlaceHolder').show();
                });
            } else if ($('#ddlVis').val() == "Hidden") {
                $('#partialPlaceHolder').hide();
            }
        });

        function ddlChanged() {
            alert("projectPtIndChanged")
            if ($('#ddlVis').val() == "Hidden") {
                alert("in hide");

                //debugger;

                $("#divHideTest").hide();

                // now let's show the partial
                var newString = "Ickle";
                $.get('/Test/DDLChangedAction' + newString, function (data) {
                    $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
                });
            } else {
                alert("in show");
                $("#divHideTest").show();
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PartialModel

<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>PartialTest</legend>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartialInt)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialInt)</dd>
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartialString)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialString)</dd>
            <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartialString2)</dt>
            <dd>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartialString2)</dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: You are currently using a form post but for your needs you will need to use ajax instead.  Using ajax you can contact the server without having to refresh the entire page after you hit "save".

Comment: Will that allow the model to be passed back and forth?

Comment: Yes.  You will submit some sort of ajax request to the server and have it return the model.  Then in the `success` portion of the ajax you will receive the model in javascript.  However, this will bypass a view as you will just be returning the object model itself, not html.  You then use jQuery to change the DOM with the model's info (like displaying a name or something like that).

Comment: Check out this example:  https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-Example.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the example you quoted creates a new PersonModel which wipes out the existing Name and DateTime. I need to pass the model into the action to propagate any changes that were made.

Comment: I'm starting to think there is only one solution: make sure every field I need is either in an input or hidden field and post back to the server whenever I need to change anything. It seems to be the only way to modify the model in any meaningful way. (Man, do I miss OnSelectedIndexChanged!)

Comment: You don't necessarily need all fields.  For example, if all a person can change is their name then you need the id value and the new name.  On the server you get the object by id, update the name field, save to database.  If every single field is editable though, then yes you need every field available.

Comment: That's the thing. if there is only one field that can change, that works. In my case, the models are going to be large with many "sub-models". Whether or not the properties can be modified will depend on the state the page is in as well as other factors. For example, changing one DDL can have the affect of hiding partials, showing others and changing existing fields.

Comment: That's the trouble with programming... Things aren't always simple :-)

Comment: To be clear, then, there is no way on a change event to pass the model to a specific action, make some changes, return the model and refresh the view without doing an actual post? They key here being passing the model back and forth.

Comment: If you want to refresh the entire page then a form post is the best way to go.  If you don't want to refresh the entire page then use ajax.  If you use ajax then you'll use jQuery to get all of the model's values, bundle them into a json object and pass that to the server.  Once the response comes back you then update the view as needed using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with this newbie and all of your help!